# Spyder3 can't find sylk_parser

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the sylk_parser package in Spyder3. I installed with
`pip3 install sylk_parser`, but when I run the code the console prompts

```
File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sylk_parser/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from sylk import SYLK

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sylk'
```

I'm additionally using Spyder with Python 2.7.8 where everything works out fine. Therefore I guessed Spyder3's environment needed to be changed BUT when I click at the stated filepath to sylk.py, the file exists. The class SYLK exists as well. What is the problem here, can someone explain to me and help me out?

Thanks to everyone!